# Want to re-create table when running rake db:seed

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to remove all tables and re-created the db when I run

```
rake db:create
```

The reason is the id's on the tables are not set to 1, so I figured i can just re-create the db if its possible, or call truncate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 rake db:reset
```

may be what you are looking for. or...

```
 rake db:drop
 rake db:create
```

Comment: this works but for test db, I want to do it for dev (but test is good also )

Comment: just use the flag  RAILS_ENV=production , you can specify your environment this way

Answer (score 1):

Try `rake db:reset` (in Rails 3)

In Rails 2, maybe this will help: http://pivotallabs.com/users/alex/blog/articles/305-collapsing-migrations

Comment: I want to do this for either test or development, can I specify?